# Javascript: Loading javascript dependencies inside JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to load Javascript files that a local js file dependent on them .. the files are external on a website 
is there a way to load all dependencies at once

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){
  alert("Script loaded and executed.");
  // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I usually load jquery in the head section, then I load the remaining scripts with dependencies inside $(document).ready(). This script ensures to load every js one by one in a synchronous way to avoid conflicts.

```
          var $apis =[                      
                        "/assets/js/script1.js",                    
                        "/assets/js/script2.js"
                    ];

        var deferred = new $.Deferred(), step = deferred;
        $.each($apis, function(i, val) {
            step = step.then(function() {
                return $.getScript(val, function() {
                    if(i==$apis.length-1) {   
                        // initialize here after all scripts are loaded
                    }
                });                     
            });        
        });    
        deferred.resolve();
```

Comment: ok let me show you the script i'm try to load it may have something wrong int cause it still give me exception with your answer 
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/com.jumbotron.javascript/jquery.jumbotronmediaplayer.js

Comment: check this Plunker example
http://plnkr.co/edit/WwAI4zYlIKa2IwII4WgQ